# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /updateprofile User has no profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, attributeerror

i have one model userprofile which is connected to User by onetoone relationship. i am trying to create combined form for both user and userprofile form but it is showing onetoonedescripter has no attribute _meta.

views.py

'''
def UpdateProfile(request):

```
if request.method =='POST':
    EUF_form = EditUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user )
    EPF_form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.Profile )
    if EUF_form.is_valid() and EPF_form.i_valid():
        EUF_form.save()
        EPF_form.save()
        return HttpResponse("Profile updated succesfully.")
        return render(request, 'profile_page.html')
else:
    EUF_form = EditUserForm(instance=request.user)
    EPF_form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {'EUF_form':EUF_form, 'EPF_form':EPF_form})
```

'''

models.py
'''
class Profile(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
bio = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='')
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', blank=True)
birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, default='1990-12-01')
website = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=256)
gender = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, choices=[('M','Male'), ('F','Female'),('O','Other')])


def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

'''

forms.py
'''
class EditUserForm(ModelForm):

```
first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'text','name': 'first_name'}),
    label="First Name")
last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'text','name': 'last_name'}),
    label="Last Name")
username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'text','name': 'username'}),
    label="Username")
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'text','name': 'email'}),
    label="Email")

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name','last_name','username','email']
```

class EditProfileForm(ModelForm):

```
mobile = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'tel','name': 'mobile'}),
    label="Phone number")
bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,
    label="Bio")
birthday = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'date','name': 'birthday'}),
    label="Username")
website = forms.URLField(widget=forms.URLInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'url','name': 'website'}),
    label="website")
gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('M','Male'), ('F','Female'),('O','Other')],
    widget=forms.Select ,
    label="gender")


class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['mobile','bio','birthday','website','gender']
```

'''

Comment: once change your model name to Profile and than make changes in your instances  to this 'instance=request.user.profile'. Dont forget to change everything related to Profile after this.

Comment: @ngawang13 thank you sir, but now after updation it is showing new error that user has no profile

Comment: its stating that your user doesnt have a profile. you need to have a profile for every user registered.

Comment: @ngawang13 sir still showing error can i contact you personally?

Comment: did you create profile for every user including the super user(admin).

Comment: @ngawang13 yes, now it is showing - NameError at /updateprofile
name 'user' is not defined.   in 10th line of views.py

Comment: did you import the auth user and this instance=request.user.Profile should be instance=request.user.profile

Comment: @ngawang13 yes i imported auth user and corrected instance=request.user.profile

Comment: So, still getting the same error?

Comment: @ngawang13 yes sir.  [link](https://github.com/burhanj888/social-media-practice) here is link to my github code for same.